# Por que usar tipo de dado e não usar só Varchar?

Tags: banco-de-dados, tipagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou manipulando alguns bancos de dados em que a grande maioria das colunas estão com o tipo de dados `VARCHAR` para campos como Data, Preço, Valor Total, Nascimento, Data/Hora e etc. Resumidamente, praticamente tudo está em varchar.

Pelo menos as tabelas que tive que criar mais tarde eu decidi colocar no tipo de dado que aquela coluna se destina pois, para mim, fica mais fácil na hora da programação manipular estes dados.

Mas o pessoal onde eu trabalho "pegam no meu pé" por eu decidir usar tipos de dados diferentes de `VARCHAR`. Certa hora acalorou até uma discussão por conta disso. Disseram que era bobeira e perda de tempo.

Entretanto, creio que há benefícios em especificar o tipo de dado, principalmente por ser mais fácil a manipulação durante a programação e por ocupar menos espaço no banco de dados (está correta essa minha afirmação?).

Existem mais benefícios em especificar o tipo de dado em que cada coluna se destina em um banco? Melhor ainda, existe algum tipo de estudo que trata os benefícios de utilizar certos tipos de dados durante o armazenamento ou execução de um programa de um projeto?

Comment: Na maioria das vezes os campos com tipo especificado podem possuir um certo tipo de optimização para aquele tipo, alem de é claro, se por acaso e por exemplo houver uma falha na validação nos dados e existir a tentativa de inserir um campo que tenha algum texto que não seja alfanumérico em um campo no banco que esteja com o tipo integer vai ocorrer um erro de inserção.

Comment: [1: fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885635/3956218) e  [Um exemplo básico mas não muito distante da sua realidade (Observe os comentários)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) Nesse caso podemos ter uma certa diferença de performance entre os tipos `varchar` e `char` dependendo do tipo de dados que você quer gravar no bd

Answer (score 1):

Eu penso que você está completamente certo em usar os tipos corretos para cada campo. De relance posso citar três desvantagens em usar varchar para tudo:

- Diminuição da compreensão semântica : o tipo ajuda na compreensão mais rápida da utilidade do campo.
- Apresentação de resultados e restrições : a depender do tipo as comparações realizadas em consultas podem gerar resultados inesperados. No exemplo abaixo o resulta seria para idades>'18' retornaria Maria que tem 9 anos (em razão da ordem alfabética utilizada para varchar considerar '9'>'18').

  ```
          create table Pessoa(
              pk_id int primary key identity(1,1),
              idade varchar(3),
              nome varchar(10),
          );

          insert into  Pessoa(idade, nome) 
          values
          ('17', 'José'),
          ('9', 'Maria'),
          ('11', 'Antonio'),
          ('22', 'Julia');

          select * 
          from Pessoa
          where idade>'18';
  ```
- Outro problema seria o uso de funções de agrupamento como AVG e SUM que não seriam possíveis para calcular valores a partir de varchar.

Acredito que existam ainda mais problemas além desses que citei, se puder dê uma lida em [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple-database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/#peterson), alguns problemas parecidos que ocorrem durante a modelagem de banco.